# Counting repeated triples

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQL db with several million triples stored. A large portion of the triples are repeated at least once. What is the most practical way to count the number of times that every triple occurs in the db? Thanks.

Comment: What does the table look like?

Comment: It looks pretty much just like the demo from the answer below (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/693c4/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing that the "triple" is made up of three columns `c1`, `c2`, and `c3`, you can use `group by` to count the distinct tuples:

```
  select c1, c2, c3, count(1)
    from mytable
group by c1, c2, c3
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/693c4/2

Comment: This query essentially creates a table-like data structure, right? If I want to put this data into an actual MySQL table in the same database as the original, is there an easy way to do that without having to do a for loop over the results of this query? Thank you.